# How do I get the ID of a clicked node in cytoscape.js?

Tags: cytoscape.js

This example in the documentation:

```
  cy.on('click', function(evt){
      console.log( 'clicked ' + this.id() );
});
```

Results in:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'id'
```

And evt.cyTarget.data() returns undefined.

Answer (score 12):

The .id() function works on elements, but you don't have an element in your event handler.  You bound to the core without any delegate element selector, so you bound to the core itself -- meaning the reference to `this` points to `cy`.

This is probably what you meant:

```
cy.on('click', 'node', function(evt){
      console.log( 'clicked ' + this.id() );
});
```

Comment: Your code works, I just wonder why the example code from cytoscape.js website cause no id error. cy.on('tap', 'node', function(evt){
  var node = evt.target;
  console.log( 'tapped ' + node.id() );
});

Comment: `evt.target` is necessarily a node because of the delegate selector.

Answer (score 9):

I use this for 2.x:

```
    cy.on('tap', 'node', function (evt) {
         console.log(evt.cyTarget.id())
    });
```

Or for 3.x:

```
    cy.on('tap', 'node', function (evt) {
         console.log(evt.target.id())
    });
```

Comment: Yes, but how do you access the data from an event in my vue.js 3 component?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the [documentation for accessing data](http://cytoscape.github.com/cytoscape.js/#collection/data/eles.data), you access element data with the `eles.data()` method. In your case it would be that you defined the id as the node name, then it's just a matter of calling

```
console.log('clicked ' + this.data('id'));
```

Comment: Thanks, this results in:
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: Actually, it works if I do this (slight modification of https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/blob/master/debug/init.js):
https://gist.github.com/dtenenba/4733384